# how to retrieve proc metadata (list of column and types) with out using 'WITH RESULT SET'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, proc

I have a collection of many stored procedures (over 500) that i need to make a ducumention of them for backend team. They need to know list of arguments , their types and also list of outputs and their types.
procedures are written by dymanic sql and last result is to use 'With Result Set' but this solution needs to open every procedure and alter it!!!
would you suggest me a reasonable solution?

Comment: You could use [`sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: i have try it but it doesnt work either! it shows this message: The metadata could not be determined because statement 'EXEC (@sqlCommand)' in procedure 'USP_Report_FinalFileAmountAlarm'  contains dynamic SQL.  Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.

Comment: If you are using dynamic SQL, that *implies* that the result sets will be different each time the procedure is run though, no? If so, what are you hoping to achieve here?

Comment: i knew...but first thing is I MUST FIND A WAY :D and 2nd, we have tried to make same result set manually, by putting null....i hope this thing help :/

Comment: Must find a way to what? As I mentioned, if it's dynamic SQL then the results set will be different for each run, so you can't document what columns are returned, as you *don't know* until you run it.

Comment: uhumm...ok, thank you :)